# How do you move a vertex a specific amount in one axis in 2.8?

Tags: modeling

How do you move a vertex a specific amount say 0.375 in the x direction. I know you do the G grab function but can you specify the distance you want to move a vertex?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Grab function (<kbd>G</kbd>), then press the key of the axis you want to move on (e.g. <kbd>X</kbd> for the X axis). Then you can type in the amount you want to move (e.g. 0.75 = move 0.75 BU).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Any idea how to do it if you have a direction other than one of the x,y.z axes?

Comment: Additional directions include the in-the-middle directions. You can do Shift-[whatever axis is not included in the direction]. For example, to move on the XY plane, do G and then Shift-Z.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode, select one vertex.  Press the "N" Key. The Transform Menu should open up on the right.  If your vertex is selected it should appear in the transform window with x,y,and z coordinates. Move your cursor to the axis you want to change, delete the present value and change the value to the coordinate that you want.  Hit Enter, voila.

Comment: You so totally Rock!!! Thank you so much!